# UIImageView - Fixed width & Flexible height?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

```
CGRect imageLocation = CGRectMake(startingXCoordinate, startingYCoordinate + detailedTitleLabel.frame.size.height + marginY, 280, 300);
self.detailedImageView.frame = imageLocation;
```

This is the code I've got so far. You can see the width is 280 and the height is 300 for now...  In the interface builder, I also set this image view as **'Aspect Fit'** to keep the ratio.

The problem here is... for some bigger or smaller images, they're located in the centre of the UIImageView and it naturally creates some extra top & bottom margins. How can I make a perfectly fitting UIImageView not ruining the ratio with 280 width?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can your images be wider than 280px or is it just the height that varies from one image to the other ?

Comment: Every pic has different size. However, I'd say the minimum width is 280px.

Comment: btw, I just hard-coded the solution.. for those who may have the same question in the future...

Comment: CGRect imageLocation = CGRectMake(startingXCoordinate,                                       startingYCoordinate + detailedTitleLabel.frame.size.height + marginY,
                                      280,                                      (280 * expectedImageSize.height)/expectedImageSize.width);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try aspect fill instead of aspect fit? That should have solved your issue, I think.